# Slider range with custom styles and dynamic values

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, nouislider

I'm working on slider for which I want some odd behaviour. I was looking for solutions and librarys but didn't find nothing that fully fits what I need and I have some problem with building it.

I'm trying to create slider for range value. With steps, dynamic min and max value.
Also I found problematic to work with style effect.

Example:

slider with range from 0 - 50

step set to 10

min value is 16 (start value should be same) - to this point slider should be red

start point should be on 16 (which is hard to make when I want steps)

when value is >16 different color and for everything that is not selected like regular grey.

[image: this is simple example for what i have in my mind]

I was trying to use nouislider and overall everywhere I could. If anyone has any idea or solution I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up in noUiSlider using the ["non-linear ranges"](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/#section-non-linear) and ["padding"](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-padding) features.

Basicaly, you'd set up three ranges:

- 0 to 16, no step
- 16 to 20, step of 4
- 20 to 50, step of 10

You'd then disable the first sub range by setting a padding of `[16, 0]`.

The styling you've described can be achieved by [styling](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-styling) `.noUi-target` with your background colors.

Comment: Thank you, I had to made some adjustments to what i wanted and what you said but this point me to good direction :)